# Responsive tile content issue. How to always display image above text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently developing a page which has a need for alternate content to be responsive but with the image remaining above the text for each section. So for example, here is a mock up of how the page layout looks:

[image]

With responsive columns, this is how the page looks on a mobile device:

[image]

As you can see the image is below the text for 2nd, 4th, 6th sections and so forth.

So, when reduced down in size, the image for each section is always shown before the text for each section. We have tried various methods and cant seem to get this to work.

Any css examples and help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you posted some examples of what you've tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

With the information you provide, here is a quick solution using `float: left` and `float: right` properties when not using a small screen, depending on if the row is odd or even. Here is the main CSS code:

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  div {
    width: 50%;
  }
  li:nth-child(2n) > div.image {
    float: left;
  }
  li:nth-child(2n + 1) > div.image {
    float: right;
  }
  li:nth-child(2n) > div.text {
    float: right;
  }
  li:nth-child(2n + 1) > div.text {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

And here is the complete example code:
https://jsfiddle.net/zxba9mw3/